# Databinding not working for EditText in Android

Tags: android, data-binding

I am trying to implement a simple data binding in my project. I am trying to remove space from my entered text in EditText, but it fails in compilation time. Following are the codes.
Could anyone please help ?

Custom BindingAdapter class

```
    public class BindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("nospace")
    public static void setText(TextView textView, boolean value) {
        
    }
} // I also tried with signature public static void setText(TextView textView, String value)
```

layout xml

```
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_lastname"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:nospace="true" />
```

Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    Log.w("MainFragment", "onCreateView...");
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    MyViewModel mainViewModel = MyViewModel .getInstance();
    binding.setMyViewModel(mainViewModel);
    return binding.getRoot();
}
```

ViewModel

```
    public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private static MyViewModel myViewModel;
    private User user;

    private MyViewModel() {
    }

    public static MyViewModel getInstance() {
        if(myViewModel == null) {
            myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        }
        return myViewModel;
    }
   }
```

Error I am getting is  `AAPT: error: attribute nospace (aka com.example.portfolio:nospace) not found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Guys I completed the whole requirement. Thanks for your support.

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/first_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_lastname"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:nospace="@{true}" />    

    public class BindingAdapters {
 
    @BindingAdapter("nospace")
    public static void setNospace(EditText editText, boolean value) {
        
        if(value) {
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(s != null && s.toString().contains(" ")) {
                        editText.setText(s.toString().replace(" ", ""));
                        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the work for you.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_lastname"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:nospace="@{true}" /> //in databinding you should always use @{}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. now adpater method is being invoked. But it is invoked on Fragment loading, i.e. only one time. I need to invoke it on every character entry. What do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
@BindingAdapter("app:nospace")
public static void setText(TextView textView, boolean value) {
    
}
```

The entire name of the attribute needs to match, so either include app: in code or remove app: in xml